# Yahoo messenger API - error when open a long-lived connection for Comet-style notification

Tags: android, yahoo-messenger

I'm trying to get Yahoo messenger notifications (comet style) to work on my Android app but I got a problem:

I have all the oauth tokens + IM cookie, I make the call to notify server but it responds with 
 403 Bad IM cookie or URI credential

The IM cookie which is sent is correct because it is the same as the one I got from POST /session.

The call:

POST to:http://rproxy2.messenger.yahooapis.com/v1/pushchannel/user_id?sid=T3qRkifs3BiGXCW4LOSoThi3lG2HvWNagr.mGA--&rand=-1131022177&count=10&seq=1&format=json&IM=2x5A0IOr9Js_8er8BgSYUCB9fjB.d20FbKds7NdJdkzWK4u2A92k5dMrM72OetLz9.q70NQCwZpAqafQ5.XM-|QTvOT1rY3ukBC8o4Z0zeRg--&oauth_consumer_key=dj0yJmk9cFNKb2NKbTdINEtFJmQ9WVdrOVpHMW1aVXhKTjJNbWNHbzlNamcyTnpNMU1UWXkmcz1jb25zdW1lcnNlY3JldCZ4PWJh&oauth_nonce=939bc51c9a594c7cbf903643bc10f7d1&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_timestamp=1328108171163&oauth_token=A%3DosG_yqL.hxped9sV4ZMVD2A5vugclvEOSKIw85DOg17vQa8N1jQK6UcGqeLGLXKFalrxnYA_iA_ArmhbN6oJ_CEINGwiq7MWsVjO_vQT5bwhmcBMwBLByhusduuH2BFJw1Zd2w_uDj5fEUVMK9bMDzg.fYEpdm1uK.*OgwyYLPCwdkzW0w6ujPpaFAea7gwmsSBYHECzjXm8wduoe1Sw3rpJH4z9PGIe8Hkt3wrbyJpW9BuiU4g6OyE1f8nhzHVkcG*_70KQiIR_oV3tP8_l4SCsbbHMvSzlyZjK1V6gJp0Q94fAcfuIWQ1Vd.iD.UZPEyzdzYK.k5Q6pE4H3At8czcXFOpmOL5eUwfbeQEtXePCL1b2v9oY4BxtH_dCUVTMhzQsV.YpKZV.ZRZzK8ThveL5gfGuqYcBZLHwVilQnQWo477XwT10GbvWUzJ2EH4v5m9q.sGMViSIKWjbE2O6YfwhYXAgQMA3d8wQLL7IoY4QC0.IR4T8M_KnZVlKoi_EiED8VuK9h7h3emBZeXoM15rqGk2..HUJQEuIe1d0YbTPEGKdM.fbCcT7_Y0Szzw3abf9b1Xjzm8VkNSKL.LXAmy8c9PyNatUT_hKFmzmWMd1RRYfd8rF7i6i7Ec_cVv06QhwCQyKlEsCQh7UChUe9JykUmiA6JOm4JOpsbTQWS1Iec35zrltc4YwouUlMx.y6JbzB_VYL9jkzeuu&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=2cd720831677df11508571218aed6c36c9cf2b51%26e57b0e111092b000a43b4ae9c928178fd5da4b9f
connection: keep-alive

cookie: IM=2x5A0IOr9Js_8er8BgSYUCB9fjB.d20FbKds7NdJdkzWK4u2A92k5dMrM72OetLz9.q70NQCwZpAqafQ5.XM-|QTvOT1rY3ukBC8o4Z0zeRg--

User-Agent: Dalvik/1.2.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; sdk Build/FRF91)

Host: rproxy2.messenger.yahooapis.com

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: 0

The server responds with:
HTTP/1.1 403 bad IM cookie or URI credentials

Connection: close

I followed all the instrunctions from [docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch02s03.html#apinotificationmanagement), not sure how can make it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP POST is empty (Content-Length: 0), the docs state:

```
Note: even though all inputs are optional, the server 
still expects an empty POST body (JSON: "{}")
```

so, change your Content-Type to "application/json;charset=utf-8" and include

```
{}
```

as the body of the HTTP POST.

Answer (score 1):

Long lived connections need to be GET calls; see "Notification Management (Comet-Style Push) API", [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch02s03.html#apimessagemanagement).